# One section is overlapping on second one

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've created two sections in **.left-column**. One is a contact form while the second one is a footer. Why footer (red square) is overlapping on the contact form?

[image]

**HTML Code:**

```
<div class="hero-wrapper">
        <div class="hero-wrapper-left-column">
            <div class="contact-form-wrapper">
                <form id="wf-form-contact-form" name="wf-form-contact-form" class="contact-v1-form">
                    <h1 class="contact-v1-heading">work with scotty</h1>
                    <p class="contact-v1-text">I help people go after their dreams and desires every day. The only difference between you and them? The action we take together. Reach out and I will get back to you ASAP my friend.</p>
                    <input type="text" class="input" maxlength="256" name="contact-name" placeholder="Your name" id="contact-name">
                    <input type="email" class="input" maxlength="256" name="contact-email" placeholder="Email Address" id="contact-email">
                    <input type="text" class="input" max_length="25" name="contact-phone" placeholder="Phone" id="contact-phone">
                    <select name="" id="select" class="w-select">
                        <option value>Select one...</option>
                        <option value="first">Mentorship</option>
                        <option value="second">Interview</option>
                        <option value="third">Speaking Engagement</option>
                    </select>
                    <textarea id="contact-message" class="input" maxlength="5000" placeholder="Describe your work" name=""></textarea>
                    <input type="submit" value="Send Message" class="contact-button">
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="footer-wrapper">
                
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="hero-wrapper-right-column"></div>
        </div>
</div>
```

**CSS code / I think rest of code isn't necessary**

```
.hero-wrapper-left-column {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100vh;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
.hero-wrapper-left-column::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0px;
    background: transparent; /* make scrollbar transparent */
}
.hero-wrapper-right-column {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100vh;
    float: right;
    background: url("../images/124194403_368759027881909_2335501689886405506_n.jpg") no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}
.hero-wrapper-left-column .contact-form-wrapper {
    width: 85%;
    height: 80%;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
 }
.hero-wrapper-left-column .contact-form-wrapper .contact-v1-form {
    display: table;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your footer and contact classes are overlapping one another because of this snippet of code.

```
.hero-wrapper-left-column .contact-form-wrapper {
    width: 85%;
    height: 80%;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute; <===== Here
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0; <===== To Here
 }
```

**The issue...**
Here you are positioning the .contact-form-wrapper to the coordinates `top: 0, left: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0` of the parent relative element .hero-wrapper-left-column. This will render your .contact-form-wrapper on the top left corner of .hero-wrapper-left-column. Since .contact-form-wrapper is being rendered at a specific location, your .footer-wrapper element ignores the bounding box of .contact-form-wrapper, hence the overlap.

**To Fix...** Remove
`position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;` properties. You will be left with the following code.

```
.hero-wrapper-left-column .contact-form-wrapper {
    width: 85%;
    height: 80%;
    margin: auto;
 }
```

If you would like to learn more about the position CSS property, please read: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position.